# How to get token_id and access_token values from Angular Session object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cookies, session-variables

I am very new to angular js  and i am trying to fetch the session_token from browser login and pass it to the backend ,i have below code :

```
console.log(this.sso.getLoginid(localStorage.getItem("at")))
  let loginid=this.sso.getNtid(localStorage.getItem("at"));
  this.loginid=loginid.loginid
  let username=loginid.name
  this.username=username
  var sessionControl = localStorage.getItem("at")
  console.log(sessionControl)
```

and sessionControl value is below when i found using debugging in console:

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImprdSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBwc3NvLnVhYS5zYXVzdmRjMDIucGNmLmRlbGwuY29tL3Rva2VuX2tleXMiLCJr","id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImprdSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBwc3NvLnVhYS5zYXVzdmRjMDIucGNm"}
```

Please help me in storing access_token and id_token in a variable using sessionControl  object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse to convert sessionControl in a object and than get sessionControl.acces_token content.